# Error 80073cf6 while installing my app on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, installation

I've just developed an app for Windows Phone 8.1 that is just been 
published on the Store. But when i try to install on a Windows Phone Device on the final part of the installation process the phone gives me this error: **80073cf6**
I don't know what to do i've found some guides on internet to fix that but nothing. I've already tried to Hard Reset the phone but nothing.
Can someone help me please?

**EDIT**

visual studio says Installation failed, contact manufacturer, but this is appening after the app where deployed in the store

Comment: Was it really a hard reset? You have wiped all of the apps and personal data from it?

Comment: yes i'ts a test phone, the problem is visual studio says Installation failed, contact manufacturer, but this is appening after the app where deployed in the store

Comment: Wait...I am lost. Your app has been published to the store and after that you can't deploy it to the phone?