# windows phone deployment error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290 ‭

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-mobile, windows-dev-center

Working on a Windows Phone 10 app and ran it from Visual Studio on my ARM (Lumia 950) device several times. Then an OS update came in for my 950 and it soon did a forced reboot; updating to 10.0.14393.576.

I may have had one or two successful deploys/debug launches from VS to the phone after that but then this error started and I am blocked.

```
DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290
```

This comes after the app has apparently successfully deployed and is trying to launch the app.

I tried several battery-pull reboots of the phone and rebooting the PC. The app is not installed on the phone (in the app list.)
I went to the Store to install a few apps and uninstall a few to see if that un-jarred it.
But nothing worked. Trying to avoid a hard reset if possible.

I found one instance of this error here:
[Error 80073cf6 while installing my app on windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343432/error-80073cf6-while-installing-my-app-on-windows-phone-8-1)
But that's pretty old and unresolved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I had deleted a splash screen image but left a reference to it in the package.manifest so it was looking for when launching on the phone. When I added back the splash screen it deployed and ran successfully.

Comment: I met the same issue with you, I have tried remove add a splash screen, but unsuccessful. Can you have any suggestion?

Comment: I used the UWP tile generator which generated all or most tiles. That may be why it was touchy (lots of tiles.) I later noticed it may not have been me. I tweaked one tile and the path to another one was removed. So I'd suggest 1st walking through every link you have in the app manifest and make sure each logo/image path that is a valid path and points to a file with the right dimensions. if that doesn't maybe try to use the [UWP tile generator](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/02/15/uwp-tile-generator-extension-for-visual-studio/#IfzWLZ0eiVUMRI6b.97) to auto-set everything