# ID_CAP_ENTERPRISE_SHARED_DATA causing Windows Phone Deployment DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1

One of my windows phone 8.1 apps will not longer deploy to an emulator or device.  I am using visual studio 2015 and deploying was working previously but I have not made changes to this application in a while so I do not know when deployment would have stopped working for it.

Deploying other apps still works.

The error is:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>
> Error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290 AppName

What are the possible causes and fixes for this error?

I ran repair on visual studio but that did not help. I have also done a factory reset on the device.

A related question indicates the error relates to Visual assets? Related Question: [windows phone deployment error dep0001 unexpected error 2147009290](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171445/windows-phone-deployment-error-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147009290)

Output from deploy to Device.

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: MyApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 1>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
>
> 1>Updating the layout...
>
> 1>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
>
> 1>Registering the application to run from layout...
>
> 1>DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Deploy to Emulator is the same except for a warning

> 1>------ Build started: Project: LockdownRoleSwitcher, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 1>  LockdownRoleSwitcher -> C:\Users\JaredStroeb\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2459,5): warning : APPX4001: Build property AppxBundlePlatforms is not explicitly set and is calculated based on currently building architecture. Use 'Create App Package' wizard or edit project file to set it.
>
> 2>------ Deploy started: Project: LockdownRoleSwitcher, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 2>Deploying to Phone Internal Storage...
>
> 2>Updating the layout...
>
> 2>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
>
> 2>Registering the application to run from layout...
>
> 2>DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I discovered an MSDN question that appear to have a similar (if not identical) issue. [MSDN Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/547f1542-ce82-406c-a22d-acd8e1d077dd/0x80073cf6-error?forum=visualstudiogeneral) fixed the issue by creating a new empty app and moving over all files.  I guess that is my next step unfortunately.

**UPDATE:**

This error appears to be caused by my WindowsPhoneReservedAppInfo.xml file using
`<SoftwareCapability Id=" ID_CAP_ENTERPRISE_SHARED_DATA " />`  I am deploying to enterprise phones by side loading currently with no plans to move my application to the windows store.  I need this software capability because my devices are locked down with a wehlockdown.xml file with defined roles.  The sole purpose of this application is to allow switching between the defined roles in my lock-down file.

I am targeting two OS Version on my devices (Panasonic FZ-E1).  The higher (OS Version 8.10.15165.177) gets the error. While the lower (Os Version 8.10.15155.167) has no error deploys and works correctly.

Is there alternative to using ID_CAP_ENTERPRISE_SHARED_DATA?

Is there a different/better way to allow switching between lock-down roles?

**Update** again

I upgraded the older OS version to match the other device, and the deploy and run still functioned as expected on the device. I no longer believe it is a problem on the OS version.  I never figured out what the problem was but it started magically working both test devices...

Problems that go away on there own usually come back on there own so if anyone has any ideas on why there was an issue to begin with I would still appreciate it.

Comment: The relating question means it could relate to any asset. Do a rebuild and then a Deploy and watch the Output window for both actions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman nothing suspicious or interesting in the rebuild output. I will include the deploy output in an edit.

Comment: we had this twice on a Windows 10 dev machine with vs2015 and both times, a reboot has helped... is the deploy output the same when you select the emulator? tried switching debug/release, clean & rebuild solution already?

Comment: @dlatikay I have tried restarting and just did again for good measure.  I have ran clean and rebuild.  I did not attempt switching debug/release before posting but after testing they both result in the error

Comment: hm. do you happen to have it in source control and can you go back to a known good changeset/get latest with overwrite, or at least browse diffs, if we keep assuming a missing/corrupted asset?

Comment: -2147009290 would be HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, "Package could not be registered". googled it, but nothing helpful so far - only user problems with windows 10 store, nothing with vs2015. does the windows event log have entries related to those errors?

Comment: @dlatikay On my computer I do not see anything in the logs that would explain.  I am not familiar with any way of viewing Event Logs on windows 8.1 phone.

Comment: @dlatikay I can explicitly create an App Package in VS.  I thought that was just for windows store, but I will see what the App Package wizard says.

Comment: @dlatikay can you take a look at my update a specific software capability seems to be unavailable due to a OS Version difference. Any ideas?