# Error when deploy uwp application (DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

When I try to deploy my uwp application to my device(OS:windows phone 10), this error appears "DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147009290"

I have read some similar question, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171445/windows-phone-deployment-error-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147009290.%20But%20this%20error%20still%20appears)? But maybe it can not help me.

Can anyone help me to figure out?

Thanks

Comment: I was facing the same issue all of a sudden.. Restarting my device fixed the issue.. also,try replacing all splashscreen images in the manifest file..

Comment: Have you enabled the developer mode for the device? Have you tried to restart the device? Does your app run on desktop? Not the same error, but may be [worth to try](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36384375/2681948). If possible give also a try to different USB cable. Are you able to deploy any other app/were able before?

Comment: The error code is `0x80073cf6` in hexdecimal display. It has the symbolic constant `ERROR_INSTALL_REGISTRATION_FAILURE`. [Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973484.aspx) offers steps to further diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The other post which you linked to did not work for me either.  Not sure if this is your scenario or not, but I already had my app installed on the device from previous builds.  Simply uninstalling it from the phone and then running the deploy again fixed it.